# A problem with polynomial rings an ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Define $R=\{\sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i\in \mathbb{Q}[X], a_0\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $I=\{\sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i\in \mathbb{Q}[X], a_0=0\}$.

Prove

**Part (a) $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $I$ ideal of $R$.**

To see that $R$ is a subring:

(1) It is obvious $R\subset\mathbb{Q}[x]$,

(2) $\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i\right) + \left(\sum_{i=0}^m b_iX^i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^m (a_i+b_i)X^i\in R,$

(3) $\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^m b_iX^i\right)=a_0b_0+a_0b_1x^{2}+a_0b_2x^{3}+\dots + a_0b_nx^{n^2}+\dots+a_1b_nx^{(n+1)}+\dots+a_nb_0x^n+a_nb_1x^{n+1}+a_1b_2x^{3}+\dots + a_nb_1x^{n^2}+a_1b_nx^{(n+1)}+\dots+a_nb_nx^{n^2}\in R$.

(4) Additive inverse $\sum_{i=0}^m (-a_i)X^i$

(5) Multiplicative inverse Not sure of a closed form for it. I know it exists and can be found by means of the Euclidean algorithm.

To see that $I$ is ideal

(1) Because of the condition $a_0=0$ is $I\subset R$

(2) Because of the calculation above for (3), since the elements of $I$ have a similar form, both products $ir, ri$, where $i\in I, r\in R$, are in $R$.

**Part (b) If $p_1, \dots, p_t\in I$ and are not zero, show that $p_i=\frac{m_i}{n_i}X^{k_i}+\text{ terms of higher degree}$. Also prove $\frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}X \in I$ but is not in $\sum_{i}^t Rp_i$**

I'm lost on how to do (b).

Comment: I is not an ideal of R as $X/2 \in I$ but not in R as $1/2 \notin Z$.

Comment: $I = R \cap X \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a (prime) ideal of $R$. @shrinit

Comment: But in question you said that $I=\{\sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i\in \mathbb{Q}[X], a_0=0\}$ and does $\frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}X $ belong to R.

Comment: @shrinit I don't understand your comment. The set $I$ is clearly an additive subgroup that absorbs multiplication from elements of $R$. The fact that $\frac12$ is not in $R$ does not contradict $\frac{x}{2}$ being in $I$...

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry but I still do not understand why everyone understands but me. He has written that $I \subset R$ but $x/2 \in I, x/2 \notin R$. Sorry

Comment: @shrinit but $X/2$ *is* in $R$. Set $a_0=0, a_1=\frac12, a_i=0$ for $i > 1$.

Comment: @rschwieb thank you I misread it in hurry.

Comment: @Cure : $\mathbb{Q}[X]/X \mathbb{Q}[X] \cong \mathbb{Q}$ is a field thus $X \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a maximal and prime ideal. $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $I = R \cap X \mathbb{Q}[X]$ thus (show it) $R/I$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[X]/X \mathbb{Q}[X] $, therefore $R/I$ is an integral domain and $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things mostly look fine (or at least on the right track) so I will just comment in the places it is apparently needed...

> (5) Multiplicative inverse Not sure of a closed form for it. I know it exists and can be found by means of the Euclidean algorithm.

Why are you looking for multiplicative inverses when confirming this is a ring? That isn't an axiom. In fact only $\pm 1$ will have inverses in this ring. If you were looking for the multiplicative identity, then $1$ is it.

> I'm lost on how to do (b).

<s>You should just observe that $R/I\cong \mathbb Z$, which is a domain. That means the kernel, $I$, is a prime ideal.</s>

Well, $I$ is just $X\mathbb Q[X]$, so naturally if you collect the $p_i$, you can factor out their common $X$'s to the front, until each one is of the form $X^e q_i(X)$ where $q_i(X)$ is a polynomial with nonzero constant term. Gathering up all the $X$'s in front, and multiplying all the nonzero constant terms together, you have that the lowest degree term is the product of those $X$'s and that nonzero constant.

$\frac{X}{n}\in I$ for every $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, so I'm not sure what the holdup is there.

Thinking about that last half of the last half...

Comment: But I did write Part (b). I rephrased because it might have been confusing as it was.

Comment: @Cure I got it :) We were getting by anyway..

Comment: Does (b) implies that $I$ is finitely generated?

Comment: @Cure no, I don’t think $I$ can be f.g.  The problem is you have to generate all rational multiples of X, but with only finitely many elements, you can only generate corfficients lying in a f.g. Subgroup of $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $\frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}X \in I$ suppose $\frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}X \in \sum_{i}^t Rp_i$ then you will get elements from $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_t\} \in R$ such that $\sum_{i}^t a_ip_i = \frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}X$. Now from here on I think we will make this into cases

If all $k_1's$ are strictly bigger than one then there is no way we can obtain any multiple of $X$. similarly, if any $k_i$ is strictly bigger than 1 then $a_i$ must be zero.

If some of $k_i's$ are 1 ($k_i$ cant be zero), then we get $\sum_{i}^t a_ip_i = \frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}X$  and we can reduce it further to see that actually $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all i. If it happens then we can not get $\frac{1}{2n_1\dots n_t}$.

I think I made it right this time.